# How do I connect to Libera.Chat with HexChat?

Tags: 20.04, irc, hexchat

[Libera.Chat](https://libera.chat/) has arrived and marketed itself as the successor to Freenode:

> We’re excited to announce the launch of Libera.Chat, and welcome you to a next-generation IRC network for free and open source software projects and similarly-spirited collaborative endeavours.

How do I make an SASL connection to Libera.Chat using HexChat and start using the Ubuntu IRC channels?

Comment: FYI:  the official channels are currently still on freenode; if you read https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/minutes-for-the-2021-05-19-community-council-meeting/22367 you'll note Kubuntu/Lubuntu need to be *polled* which hasn't officially occurred yet..  (*one hasn't anyway, I don't know about the other*)

Comment: @guiverc Committee's will almost almost always guarantee a slow process :)

Comment: I'm connected (*have been since yesterday*), but I'm not convinced my setup is perfect; I'll check next time i reboot.. but I followed https://libera.chat/guides/hexchat  (now using 3 networks; OFTC, Freenode (still currently official) & Libera.Chat

Comment: I connected with irssi but I was after an answer for those who prefer a GUI...

Comment: I suspected that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Libera.Chat provide a guide at https://libera.chat/guides/hexchat

> 1. Open the Network List (Ctrl + S)
> 2. If the Libera.Chat network exists in the list, then click on Edit and skip ahead to step 5
> 3. If it does not yet exist in the list, click Add and type Libera.Chat, then hit enter and click on Edit
> 4. Replace the string `newserver/6667` with `irc.libera.chat/6667`
> 5. In the *User name* field, enter your primary nick Select `SASL (username + password)` for the *Login method* field
> 6. In the Password field, enter your *NickServ* password
>
> If you are unable to edit the User name field, the change can be made
> in the User Information section on the Network List window.
>
> If everything was configured correctly, you should see a SASL
> authentication successful message when you connect. You will already
> be identified to NickServ, so you don’t need to do this again.

Note:  on my Lubuntu *impish* system I could not skip from step *2* to *5*; but that could be because my system is old (*many-many-release-upgrades*)

Comment: FYI:  Currently Freenode is still the official site (as per comments above; refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/minutes-for-the-2021-05-19-community-council-meeting/22367) but that *fact* that both the OP (`irssi`) & myself (`hexchat`) have made this move does sort of show .....

Comment: Movement is occurring... https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-irc/2021-May/001924.html  (request for launchpad users to change their pages to say libera instead of freenode..)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, just tested on my own copy of Hexchat and all is well :)

Comment: FYI:   I have more than one box; on another I just edited `~/.config/hexchat/servlist.conf` & based the detail I added from my prior entries (ie. freenode & oftc), which isn't difficult (and is my preferred option personally).  It's pretty easy, and I'll provide a link to show how easy in a change only recently made - https://github.com/Xubuntu/xubuntu-default-settings/pull/20/commits/307a83168c9120acff494ed3c3cf2b3934c53c2e  (by @[Jay Philips](https://askubuntu.com/users/375840/jay-philips))

Comment: So, why can you connect from their website through hexchat without the user name and password, and then later identify ... but when you manually add it to hexchat you have to enter user + password ... very odd.

Comment: Also, thanks for the post.  Very helpful!